# String Incrementing Function in C

Tags: c, c-strings

For my programming class, I am trying to write a function incrementstring() that takes the string 'str' passed in from a driver, and adds one to them. It should work with both letters and numbers (ex. '1' goes to '2', 'a' goes to 'b', 'z' goes to 'aa', 'ZZ' goes to 'AAA'). I have almost every test condition working, except for one bug that I can't seem to find a way around.

This is what I currently have:

```
void incrementstring(char* str){
int i;
int j;
int length = strlen(str);
for(i = strlen(str)-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if (str[i] == '9'){
            str[i] = '0';
            if (str[0] == '0'){
                    for (j = strlen(str)-1; j>=0; j--){ //This loop is the problem
                            str[j+1] = str[j];
                            }
                    str[0] = '1';
                    }
    }
    else if (str[i] == 'z'){
            if (str[0] == 'z'){
                    str[i] = 'a';
                    str[i+1] = 'a';
                    }
            str[i] = 'a';
            }

    else if (str[i] == 'Z'){
            if(str[0] == 'Z'){
                    str[i] = 'A';
                    str[i+1] = 'A';
            }
            str[i] = 'a';
    }
    else{
            str[i]++;
            return;
    }

}
}
```

When I run the function, this is what the driver outputs:

```
 1. testing "1"... = 2. Correct!
 2. testing "99"... = 100. Correct!
 3. testing "a"... = b. Correct!
 4. testing "d"... = e. Correct!
 5. testing "z"... = INCORRECT: we got "aa0". We should be getting "aa" instead.
 6. testing "aa"... = ab. Correct!
 7. testing "Az"... = Ba. Correct!
 8. testing "zz"... = aaa. Correct!
 9. testing "cw"... = cx. Correct!
 10. testing "tab"... = tac. Correct!
 11. testing "500"... = 501. Correct!

11 tests run.
```

I wrote a for loop in line 9 to handle the '99' to '100' condition. It takes every index of the string and shifts it one to the right, and then adds a '1' to the beginning of the string. However, this loop for some reason messes up the 5th test condition, as seen above. If I take the loop out, '99' will go to '00', but the 5th test will pass with no problems. I've hit a brick wall here and I was wondering if anybody can provide some insight.

I appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: After your "carry" (that is, when you extend the "string"), you need to add a NUL terminating byte in the array. All the `str[i+1]=` should have a `str[i+2]='\0';` after them. You also do realize you're assuming ASCII character set, right? Or is that consideration beyond the scope of the class?

Comment: Using a debugger could be helpful here too.

Comment: Your "carry" doesn't really work in all cases: Try entering 'zaz' - That should transform to 'zba', if I got your requirement right, but expands to 'zaaa'. You fail to transfer your "carry" all the way up but only look into the leading char.

Comment: On second thought, "zaz" actually increments to "zbaa" in your program. But I still think this would be wrong and should be "zba".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While also keeping track of string length to make sure you do not overwrite its allocated space, add a null terminating character to each of your `if()` and `if else` segments:

```
str[0] = '1';
str[1] = 0;
```

...

```
str[i] = 'a';
str[i+1] = 0;
```

And so on.

This final statement may not be doing what you expect it should do.
I believe what you want to do is to increment the expression to point to the next element of memory owned by`str`.
Keep in mind that `str` is actually not an array.  It is a pointer.  The `[...]`
notation you are using is a convenience provided in C to allow array like referencing of pointers.
So, the expression `str[i]` for example can also be expressed as `*(str + i)`.
If it is the next memory location (where the next `char` is stored)you want, the expression would be:
`*(str + i++)`, which when using array notation translates to: `str[i++]`

Change the following from

```
else{
        str[i]++;
```

to:

```
else{
        str[i++]=0;
```

Comment: This seemed to do the trick in addition to adding NULL terminating statements to the end of every if statement. Thank you everyone for the help, you guys are an awesome community.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're not NULL-terminating your string in the driver program. Running your code with my own driver program works perfectly, so any additional help would require you to share your driver program with us.

All you have to do is, after you fill the `char *` with the string, make the next character a `'\0'` character. Since the `strlen` function simply iterates over the array of `char`s until it reaches a NULL terminating character, you have to terminate all strings with that character before using them.

Comment: Note: In C, the uppercase NULL is best reserved for `NULL`, the null pointer constant.  Here, suggest _null character_ or `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for "zaz" correctly?